# Keep form fields from being editable

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

I have a form that's pre-populated with values from a database.  If a user is logged in and has sufficient permissions, the user can edit the fields.  That all works well; however, if the user is *not* logged in, the fields should not be able to be changed.  I have it so that any changes the bad user makes won't save to the database, but I'd like to make it so that the user can't even click into those fields.

Is there a way to conditionally allow form fields to be clickable?

Comment: Changing the look of the form isn't enough, you'll have to control the saving side of your code so only logged-in users can save. and do not display textboxes for non-logged in users, just put the data without boxes at all.

Comment: i would suggest you reconsider this approach. if a user is not logged in then just show them the info without any form.

Comment: That seems like a massive rewrite, while adding the readonly field worked pretty quickly and easily.  What's the downside?  (We are not overly concerned with security; it's merely a helper tool for internal use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the `readonly` attribute to the HTML tag, like this:

```
<input type="text" value="sample" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a disable tag in your input if the user is not logged in. For example: `<input type="text" name="lname" disabled>`

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the fields when no logged in.

```
<input type="text" name="lname" <?php print (isLoggedIn($user)?"disabled":"");?> >
```

if, for whatever reason, you don't want them to look disabled, you can use a CSS class to modify how the disabled fields look.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your session variable, you can embed a little piece of jQuery.
Say `$_SESSION['login'] == true`, then

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
           $('.showbox').attr("disabled", true);           
});
```

and similarly for `$_SESSION['login'] == false` set as enabled.

This allows you to select multiple textboxes or all of them just by adding a class or an ID to the textbox tag.